# IIS 5.1, MVC 2, SQL Server 2005 deployement error

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, iis

I have deployed a solution correctly on IIS 5.1 (hopefully) as it loads up and shows a "User not authorised page which I created myself". The fact this shows is a good sign but it also hides any errors as I think I should be authorised.

To try an get an error message I ran a method on a controller which didnt require any authorisation and the error below was thrown. I think the authorisation failure is caused by the application failing to retrieve the credentials from the database and therefore assuming the user is not authorised.

To the best of my knowledge SQL Server does allow remote connections by default. The web.config is configured correctly - the connectionstring is (Computername\default instance name) :

> Data
>   Source=LDNGPSWK2232\MSSQLSERVER;Initial
>   Catalog=NEWEMPSKILLS;Integrated
>   Security=True

Half way down the stack trace it says the underlying provider failed to open and the "C:\ ..." paths are not where the virtual directory is so Im not sure where that is coming from.

Anybody got any ideas on this?

Thanks

> Server Error in '/EmploymentSkills'
>
> ### Application.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection
>   string is not valid)  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection
>   string is not valid)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection
>   string is not valid)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   +5009598    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   +234    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds
>   connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity) +341
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection
>   owningObject) +129
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +195
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +232
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +185
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +524
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +66
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +479
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +108
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory) +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   +125    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection
>   storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String
>   exceptionCode, String
>   attemptedOperation, Boolean&
>   closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +52
>
> [EntityException: The underlying
>   provider failed on Open.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection
>   storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String
>   exceptionCode, String
>   attemptedOperation, Boolean&
>   closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +161
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   +98    System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
>   +81    System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +46
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   +44    System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +176
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__0(IEnumerable`1
>   sequence) +41
>
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot) +59
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +150
>   System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1
>   source) +265
>
>   EmploymentSkills.Repository.ProviderReturnRepository.GetAllBoroughsForProvider(Int32
>   Id) in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Alex\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\EmploymentSkillsAD12\EmploymentSkills\Repository\ProviderReturnRepository.cs:87
>   EmploymentSkills.Controllers.ProviderController.Deduping(Int32
>   MonthID, Int32 ProviderID) in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\Alex\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EmploymentSkillsAD12\EmploymentSkills\Controllers\ProviderController.cs:169
>   EmploymentSkills.Controllers.ProviderController.dedupeNOW()
>   in C:\Documents and Settings\Alex\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EmploymentSkillsAD12\EmploymentSkills\Controllers\ProviderController.cs:30
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase
>   , Object[] ) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +201
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
>   +56    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +267 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.b__c()
>   +20    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +343    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +115    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4()
>   +34    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +310    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +163
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Answer (score 0):

Is the computer name where your SQL Server is installed called 'LDNGPSWK2232'?  Is the SQL Server installed as a named instance called 'MSSQLSERVER'?  This looks exactly like the name of the default service name.  If you have a default SQL Server instance then your connection string should look like this

```
Data Source=LDNGPSWK2232;Initial Catalog=NEWEMPSKILLS;Integrated Security=True
```

You only need the server name in the Data Source.

Comment: Interesting that you pointed that out as that was the next thing I would try tomorrow. Now it definitely is. The computer name is 'LDNGPSWK2232', and the Instance is the default one and called 'MSSQLSERVER'. It does seem reasonable that I have the connection string wrong and that might just be it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ProductionServerEntities"
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyDBEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyDBEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyDBEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYSQLSERVER;attachdbfilename=C:\inetpub\domains\MyDomainName\App_Data\MyDB03.mdf;Database=MyDB06;integrated security=False;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```